# How to filter rows instead of columns in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I have a shared google sheet at work that would look like what is down below. I want to filter out all the rows that have 0's in all 3 columns. I've tried a =filter function, but the problem with it is that it only does 1 row/column at a time. Any ideas?

```
value 1 value 2 value 3
8485    2515    0
121     0       0
36      0       415
0       0       0
0       0       0
0       1551    0
```

Comment: Show the formula that you tried and add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Comment: @Marios https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64706701/revisions

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY({A:C, TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:C),,9^9))}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col4 <> '0 0 0'")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

If you want to do that using Google Apps Script, then:

```
function myFunction() {
  
const sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
const data = sheet1.getRange('A1:C'+sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();  
const fdata = data.filter(r=>r[0]!=0 || r[1]!=0 || r[2]!=0);
sheet1.getRange(1,5,fdata.length,fdata[0].length).setValues(fdata);
}
```

**Input of my sheet and output:**

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

**[Solved]:**

You can try this solution:

In new column (as example [**Column D**]) add a *Concatenate* formula like this:

```
=A1&B1&C1
```

Applicate to All Rows from row **D1** to **D7**.

[image]

Then you just Add a ***Filter*** to this column:  **[Column D]** Unselect this Value "**000**" with three zeros.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few simple solutions:

```
=QUERY(
  A:C;
  "WHERE     A IS NOT NULL
         AND A * A + B * B + C * C <> 0"
)
```

```
=QUERY(
  A:C;
  "WHERE     A IS NOT NULL
         AND (A <> 0 OR B <> 0 OR C <> 0)"
)
```

[image]